# PHP's utf8_decode and C#'s Encoding.UTF8.GetString returning different outputs for the same input

Tags: c#, php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have this PHP code that converts two byte arrays (one having 32 bytes, the other having 70 bytes) in UTF-8 strings using utf8_decode():

```
$bytes32 = [144, 204, 205, 119, 77, 176, 172, 140, 110, 162, 222, 255, 14, 38, 252, 82, 118, 138, 130, 124, 145, 199, 55, 162, 224, 80, 102, 141, 140, 57, 194, 36];
$string32 = implode(array_map("chr", $bytes32));
$string32Utf8 = utf8_decode($string32);

$bytes70 = [239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 119, 77, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 110, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 14, 38, 239, 191, 189, 82, 118, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 124, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 55, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 80, 102, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 57, 239, 191, 189, 36];
$string70 = implode(array_map("chr", $bytes70));
$string70Utf8 = utf8_decode($string70);

echo '$string32Utf8: ' . $string32Utf8; // echoes ???wM???n??&?Rv??|??7??Pf??9?$
echo '$string70Utf8: ' . $string70Utf8; // echoes ???wM???n???&?Rv??|??7??Pf??9?$
echo '$string32Utf8 === $string70Utf8: ' . json_encode($string32Utf8 ===  $string70Utf8); // echoes false
```

I then have this C# code that does the same thing using Encoding.UTF8.GetString():

```
byte[] bytes32 = new byte[] { 144, 204, 205, 119, 77, 176, 172, 140, 110, 162, 222, 255, 14, 38, 252, 82, 118, 138, 130, 124, 145, 199, 55, 162, 224, 80, 102, 141, 140, 57, 194, 36 };
string string32Utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes32);

byte[] bytes70 = new byte[] { 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 119, 77, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 110, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 14, 38, 239, 191, 189, 82, 118, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 124, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 55, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 80, 102, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 57, 239, 191, 189, 36 };
string string70Utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes70);

Console.WriteLine("string32Utf8: " + string32Utf8); // Writes ���wM���n���&�Rv��|��7��Pf��9�$
Console.WriteLine("string70Utf8: " + string70Utf8); // Writes ���wM���n���&�Rv��|��7��Pf��9�$
Console.WriteLine("string32Utf8 == string70Utf8: " + (string32Utf8 == string70Utf8)); // Writes true
```

First of all, in C#, both byte arrays result in the same string after conversion, unlike with PHP. Second, the strings are different in C# compared with PHP.

Is there a function in PHP that will actually return the same output as C#'s Encoding.UTF8.GetString() given the same input? Or is there something I'm missing that's actually resulting in the different outputs between C# and PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte arrays in your example **are not a valid UTF-8**. Basically, if you see ��� symbols in C# output, it means `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` used a replacement character to represent encoded input byte sequence that cannot be converted to an output character. Check [DecoderReplacementFallback remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.decoderreplacementfallback?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) for more details.

However, you still can reproduce the same exact behavior of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` in PHP:

```php
$bytes32 = [144, 204, 205, 119, 77, 176, 172, 140, 110, 162, 222, 255, 14, 38, 252, 82, 118, 138, 130, 124, 145, 199, 55, 162, 224, 80, 102, 141, 140, 57, 194, 36];
$string32 = \pack('C*', ...$bytes32);
$string32Utf8 = \mb_convert_encoding($string32, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8');

$bytes70 = [239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 119, 77, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 110, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 14, 38, 239, 191, 189, 82, 118, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 124, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 55, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 80, 102, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 57, 239, 191, 189, 36];
$string70 = \pack('C*', ...$bytes70);
$string70Utf8 = \mb_convert_encoding($string70, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8');

\var_dump($string32Utf8, $string70Utf8, $string32Utf8 === $string70Utf8);
```

You can test it here: https://3v4l.org/je8gf

Things I did differently:

1. Since byte array represents **UTF-8 string**, we can't use [`chr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) to convert it to a binary string. As described in `chr` function documentation:

   > this function is not aware of any string encoding, and in particular cannot be passed a Unicode code point value to generate a string in a multibyte encoding like UTF-8 or UTF-16.

   [`pack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function, on the other hand, can handle various types of binary data formats. `\pack('C*', ...$bytes32)` means that byte array will treated as a sequence of unsigned chars and packed into binary string.
2. [`utf8_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode) function has a very confusing name; it should be named something like `utf8_to_iso88591` because that is exactly what it does:

   > Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1

   If we want to replicate `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` example, what we really need to do, is to convert UTF-8 encoded binary string to ASCII. And you can do it using [`mb_convert_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding) function, just like that: `mb_convert_encoding($utf8String, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8')`

Hope these comments will help!